# My app crashed if I use dispatch_async

Tags: ios, crash, grand-central-dispatch

This code works ok.

```
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];
[parser release];
```

But if I use dispatch_async I will get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. But why?

```
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
parser.delegate = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
                {
                [parser parse];
                });
[parser release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the parsers delegate is not being released prematurely.  The parser will only hold a weak reference to the delegate and if the delegate is dealloc'ed before parsing is complete, you will get a bad access when the parser attempts to call it's delegate methods.

Comment: I places [parser release] in block and now everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reason was [parser release] happens before [parser parse]. Once after dispatching the block into a queue (the block will be there waiting for execution), [parser release] will be invoked immediately.  Keep in mind that there is an execution delay for the block when using dispatch_async.

This also explains why when you put [parser release] in the block and everything becomes fine.